# Event handler subscription on approveVariance

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I created an event handler subscription on `approveVariance` method in `VendInvoiceInfoTable`.

Here is the code of the handler:

```
public static void postApprovingPendingInvoice(XppPrePostArgs _args)
{
   VendInvoiceInfoTable vendInvoiceInfoTable;

   vendInvoiceInfoTable = _args.getThis();

   info(vendInvoiceInfoTable.PurchId + " from handler");
}
```

All god and fine if i check and uncheck the checkbox myself. I am talking about the checkbox found on VendInvoiceMatchingDetails form with label :

```
 Approve posting with matching discrepancies.
```

The problem appears when that `approveVariance` is called from a batch. The handler is not reached anymore.

Is this a correct behavior ? Is there any valid approach to this?

I think I can create a static method in a util class, and call it every time the `approveVariance` is called and send a specific parmeter. I just tried to follow the best practices.

Comment: You have to build CIL

Comment: True, it worked. So i have to build CIL in order to have the latest version of the  .dll referenced by that batch process. I was adding the event subscription but just an older .dll was available. Is that right?

Comment: @Matej please post your comment as an answer so i can accept it being a valid solution for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Matej said, you need to build the CIL (incremental or full) as batch runs in the CIL (Common Intermediate Language).

When you write code, it initially compiles into P-Code, which is interpreted by the AX runtime environment. When you build the CIL, it interprets/compiles that p-code into the CIL.

When you say "older .dll", it's more like older `*.xpp` files most likely located in `c:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Server\[aos]\bin\XppIL\source`

[Here's a great article on the CIL](http://axwonders.blogspot.com/2013/04/ax-2012-cil-how-does-it-work.html)